# Can't deploy kitchensink example

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-8

I have wildfly 8.2.0.Final installed and I'm using eclipse with jboss developer studio plugin. From the jboss central side within eclipse I started the sample kitchensink. When I try to deploy via 'mvn clean install jboss-as:deploy' I'm getting the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.4.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project jboss-kitchensink: Could not execute goal deploy on /home/vagrant/workspaces/projects1/jboss-kitchensink/target/jboss-kitchensink.war. Reason: I/O Error could not execute operation '{
[ERROR] "address" => [],
[ERROR] "operation" => "read-attribute",
[ERROR] "name" => "launch-type"
[ERROR] }': java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://localhost:9990. The connection timed out
```

What is the mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you don't mix WildFly with JBoss AS, and don't start the sample twice (from Eclipse and from Maven).

The WildFly quickstarts are [here](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart), don't use an older version targeting JBoss AS.

The `kitchensink` sample can be deployed via `mvn wildfly:deploy`, not `mvn jboss-as:deploy`.

Comment: I used jboss-as maven plugin instead of wildfly maven plugin, so that didnt work.